# Remove all rows of dataframe which include atleast x amount of values from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I  have a Dataframe with rows of sentences.
Now I would like to remove all sentences from the Dataframe which contain `>= x (e.g. 2 or 3)` amount of words of a dictionary/list which could look the following: `dict = {"ice", "water", "rain"}`

So for example, if x=2 I would like to remove the sentence `ice and water are similar to each other` because it has two words from the dictionary but not `ice melts away when it's warm` because it has less than two words from the dictionary.

I know for removing sentences which include any word from the dictionary I can do:

```
df[~df.Sentences.str.contains('|'.join(dict))]
```

So in summary I am looking for a way to remove sentences from the Dataframe which include at least x amount of values from a dictionary/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following for your use case:

```py
dict_test = {"ice", "water", "rain"}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sentences':["ice and water are similar to each other",
                 "ice melts away when it's"]
})


threshold = 2
df_grouper = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)
for word in dict_test:
    df_i = df['sentences'].str.count(word)
    df_grouper += df_i
    
result = df[df_grouper<threshold]
result
```

Basically, we count the ocurrences of each word and sum them in df_grouper. Finally, we keep only the rows that meets our conditions.

Comment: Nice!, please, don't forget to mark my answer as correct and upvote it if it helped you. :)

Comment: Marked it as correct, I am too new for upvoting :D

Answer (score 0):

First you make  a  boolean function that checks if the given row satifies your condition or not. Then you use the apply function which will create a boolean index of your dataframe(All rows that satisfy the condition will be changed to True and other rows as false). Now we can use this boolean index to filter out the rows from our dataframe(All rows which have  a false values in boolean index  will be removed )

```
def checkk(row):
 sentence = row.Sentences
 # Add your condition here and return True if sentence satisfies the condition or else false 
 return True

df= df[df.apply(checkk,axis=1)]
```